# Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed';
import ExportPdf from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-export-pdf/src/exportpdf';
```

Getting ckeditor 5 duplicate modules error

Without ExportPdf module works

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, By any changce did you find the answer?